# How to change the location where Android Studio places the imports?

Tags: android-studio, import

I am coming from Eclipse and I am used to this style:

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

But Android Studio behaves totally different and does this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private android.widget.Button b1, b2;
    private android.widget.EditText ed1, ed2;
    private android.widget.TextView    tx1;
    private android.widget.ProgressBar pb;
```

I am searching for nearly an hour now but cannot find a solution. This import style is driving me nuts already. I have to go trough thousands of lines of code to correct the imports. I know Android Studio is in beta but this is a no go for myself. The readability is horrible. Many lines in my code get wrapped like this:

```
if (ed1.getText().toString().equals("abc") &&
    ed2.getText().toString().equals("abc")) {
      android.widget.Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  Redirecting...", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
      android.widget.Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In Eclipse it does look like:

```
if (ed1.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
    ed2.getText().toString().equals("admin")) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I also went trough the settings of AS many times still hoping, I missed a setting there. But it does not seem so. Am I the only one having this trouble and is there a solution? I have to use AS at work, because Eclipse is not supported anymore by google.

Edit:
Eclipse style:

```
package test;

// Imports here
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView t;
    private EditText e;
    private ProgressBar p;
    private Button b;

    ...
}
```

AS style:

```
package test;

// mostly no imports here

public class Test extends ActionBarActivity {

    private android.widget.TextView t;
    private android.widget.EditText e;
    private android.widget.ProgressBar p;
    private android.widget.Button b;

    ...
}
```

Comment: How do you exactly import? What are your steps to get the inline code?

Comment: Do not really understand what you mean. In Eclipse I click ctrl+shift+o and he adds all necessary imports at the top of the file. If I do this in AS, it just complains "no unused imports". If check all settings in the auto import dialog, AS puts at every TextView, Button etc. in the code the full import path instead of only one time at the top of the file. Like eclipse does. If I do not check all the settings, than I have to go to every TextView (or whatever), hit alt+enter (or strg?) and he suggests an import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated AS today to [1.3](http://tools.android.com/recent) and the imports are placed how I like it.